# Java : finding the total number of divisors for a very large number in an efficient way

Tags: java

the number is 
n = 2747502308387844992
count = 0
Normal ways like using for loop is not working.

```
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(n%i == 0 ){count++;}
}
System.out.println(count%(Math.pow(10,9)+7));
```

output to be printed is **10240**.
suggest me the other way which is effiecient.
Please try the solution in IDE before putting here.

Comment: What makes you say that it "is not working"?

Comment: very big number... taking a lot of time in looping.  still not giving the expected result

Comment: There *is* no especially fast way to solve this problem. You can stop at sqrt(n), but there's not going to be a really efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could devide the number into partitions of certain ranges and then use threads to find the divisors of those intervals and add them to an ArrayList.

Let's say you want to find the divisors of 10. You could split it into the intervals of [1,5] and [6,10]. Then use 2 threads to parallel calculate the divisors.

You could also use a thread pool. Create a class which implements the Runnable interface and add a single number to the constructor. Use the run method to calculate the divisor and add it to a shared list.

Comment: Nice thinking @Bastian Schoettle
Makes some sence. thanks.

Comment: No worries! I'm sure that my first solution will be faster because you could speed up the calculation process by the number of threads. Let's say it would take 2 Minutes to calculate the divisors in a single thread, if you use 4 threads it would only take 30 seconds. This is of course depending on our system.

Answer (score 0):

```
int end = (int) Math.sqrt(x);
for(i=1;i<end;i++)
{
    if(n%i == 0 )
    {
          count=count+2;
    }

}
if(n%end == 0 && n*n==end){count=count+1;}
if(n%end == 0 && n*n!=end){count=count+2;}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: `if(n%end == 0 ){count=count+1;}` This will add one even if the number isn't a perfect square e.g. 10's divisors are 1, 2, 5, 10 but since that's an even number (you always add 2 so `count` will always be even) but there are only 4 divisors.

Comment: have you really tried for my input.... even this method taking lot of time and giving output as 64 which is not correct.

Comment: i gave you  an idea , try to implement  it using BIGDECIMAL

Comment: great idea for small numbers like 10,20 but the question completely about big numbers like the number that i mentions..  whats the point in your answer

Comment: you should iterate until square(n) , it is more more rapide than the first methode